# IStream COM read to buffer then send through winsock

Tags: c++, com, gdi+, winsock, istream

I've created a server/client through winsock2. Where the client takes a bmp screenshot, compresses it into jpeg and sends it to the server. The problem I'm having is the server is having problems saving the file onto disk. Like the data isn't receiving right. I think it has to do in the way I'm sending or receiving the buffer.

EDIT: From Setting `breakpoints` during debug it seems as if all the data was received. `istream->Write` returns correct number of bytes in correlation with `Size` and `istream->Seek` returns `S_OK` and the `CLSID` COM object contains the same data that was sent. Also before I send the buffer I test it to see if it saves and it does. Therefore I'm assuming it has to be the way  Buffer was sent or received.

EDIT:
On both ends the buffer looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr3sq.png)

Screen Shot plus send code.

```
    ScreenShot(Packet_Handler* _Handle)
{
IStream* istream;
    //char* Buff;
    HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiToken, &gdiInput, NULL);
    {
        HDC scrdc, memdc;
        HBITMAP membit;
        scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
        int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
        membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
        HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, membit);
        BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);
        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);


        bitmap.Save(istream, &clsid, NULL);
        bitmap.Save(L"Test.jpeg", &clsid, NULL); //THIS WORKS
        STATSTG pstatstg = { 0 };
        istream->Stat(&pstatstg, 0);
        ULONG Bytes;
        char* isBuff = new char[pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart];
        LARGE_INTEGER li;
        li.QuadPart = 0;
        istream->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);
        if (istream->Read(isBuff, pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart, &Bytes) == S_OK)
        {
            IStream* nistream = nullptr;
            ULONG nBytes;
            CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &nistream);
            if (nistream->Write(isBuff, pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart, &Bytes) == S_OK)
            {

                if (nistream->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL) == S_OK)

                {
                    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap2(nistream, NULL);
                    bitmap2.Save(L"Testing.jpeg", &clsid, NULL); //THIS WORKS
                }
            }
        }

        int Size = pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart;
        int SOLI = sizeof(ULARGE_INTEGER);
        int SOCID = sizeof(CLSID);
        int SOIS = sizeof(IStream);

        Send_Full_Packet(_Handle, &Size, isBuff, TRUE);
        Send_Full_Packet(_Handle, &SOCID, &clsid, FALSE);



        printf("saving Screenshot");


        DeleteObject(memdc);
        DeleteObject(membit);
        ::ReleaseDC(0, scrdc);

    }
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiToken);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
    void Send_Full_Packet(Packet_Handler* _Handle, int* pSize, void * Buff, bool ispchar)
    {
        int SentPackets = 0;
        int sCheck = 0;
        int rCheck = 0;
        int Size = *pSize;
        char* isBuff;// = new char[Size];

            sCheck = send(_Handle->ConnectSocket, (char*)&Size, sizeof(int), NULL);

        int PacketsSent = 0;
        sCheck = 0;
        int PacketsLeft = Size;
        while (PacketsSent < Size)
        {
            if (ispchar == FALSE)
            {
                SentPackets = send(_Handle->ConnectSocket, (char*)Buff + PacketsSent, PacketsLeft, NULL);
            }
            else {
                isBuff = (char*)Buff;
                SentPackets = send(_Handle->ConnectSocket, isBuff + PacketsSent, PacketsLeft, NULL);
            }
            if (SentPackets == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                if (WSAGetLastError() != 10054)
                {
                    if (WSAGetLastError() == 10035)
                    {
                        SentPackets == 0;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Sending Socket error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            PacketsSent += SentPackets;
            PacketsLeft -= SentPackets;
        }


    }
```

Receive code

```
    ScreenShot_Receive_Thread(Packet_Handler* _Handle)
{

    Packet_Handler::_Packet_Type Packet = Packet_Handler::_Packet_Type::Remote;
    while (true)
    {
        if (send(_Handle->si.Connections[_Handle->si.ConnectionCounter - 1], (char*)&Packet, sizeof(Packet_Handler::_Packet_Type), 0) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int Size = 0;
                char* Buff = NULL;
                Buff = _Handle->Receive_Full_Packet(_Handle, &Size, Buff, TRUE);
                CLSID clsid;
                int SOCID = sizeof(CLSID);
                _Handle->Receive_Full_Packet(_Handle, &SOCID, &clsid, FALSE);
                IStream* istream = nullptr;
                ULONG Bytes;
                CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);
                if (istream->Write(Buff, Size, &Bytes) == S_OK)
                {
                    LARGE_INTEGER li;
                    li.QuadPart = 0;
                    if (istream->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL) == S_OK)
                    {
                        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(istream, NULL);
                        bitmap.Save(L"Testing.jpeg", &clsid, NULL);//DOESNT WORK
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    MessageBox(NULL, L"CLient COnnection Error!", NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}


  char* Packet_Handler::Receive_Full_Packet(Packet_Handler * _Handle, int* pSize, void * Buff, bool ispchar)
{
    int rCheck = 0;
    int sCheck = 0;
    int Size = *pSize;
    rCheck = recv(_Handle->si.Connections[_Handle->si.ConnectionCounter - 1], (char*)&Size, sizeof(int), 0);
    if (rCheck == -1)
    {
        int Error = WSAGetLastError();
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        std::cout << "The Error is: " << Error << std::endl;
    }
    *pSize = Size;
    char* isBuff;// = NULL;
    int PacketsReceived = 0;
    int PacketsLeft = Size;
    int ReceivedPackets = 0;
    while (PacketsReceived < Size)
    {
        if (ispchar == FALSE)
        {
            ReceivedPackets = recv(_Handle->si.Connections[_Handle->si.ConnectionCounter - 1], (char*)Buff + PacketsReceived, PacketsLeft, 0);

        }
        else
        {
            isBuff = new char[Size]; //I Think my problem is here// 

            ReceivedPackets = recv(_Handle->si.Connections[_Handle->si.ConnectionCounter - 1], isBuff + PacketsReceived, PacketsLeft, 0);

        }
        if (ReceivedPackets == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int Error = WSAGetLastError();
            if (Error != 10054)
            {
                if (Error == 10035  || Error == 6)
                {
                    ReceivedPackets == 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    AllocConsole();
                    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
                    std::cout << "The Error is: " << Error << std::endl;
                    //MessageBox(NULL, (WCHAR*)WSAGetLastError(), NULL, NULL);
                    _getch();
                    //return NULL;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        PacketsReceived += ReceivedPackets;
        PacketsLeft -= ReceivedPackets;
    }
    return isBuff;
}
```

Comment: Do you create the `IStream` COM object successfully? I.e. do the `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` call succeed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude on the receive end? I just checked it with `if (CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream) == S_OK)` and it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Figured it out. Turns out there was absolutely nothing wrong with the way i was sending the buffer. It was actually the `CLSID`. I ended up putting the `GetEncoderClsid` function in the receiving end. Works like butter.

Answer (score 0):

The data may require multiple `recv` calls to receive fully. When this happens, `Receive_Full_Packet` allocates a new buffer for every such call, promptly leaking all but one of them. What it returns to the caller is the last such allocation - a mostly uninitialized buffer full of random garbage, with the last chunk of data at the very end of it.

Move `isBuff = new char[Size];` line outside the loop, place it right after the first `recv` call that retrieved the size.

Comment: I'll try that. but as of right now since I'm using my Local address `127.0.0.1` to listen on so it sends the full buffer in one shot.

Comment: That wasn't it but thank you. That would have highly effected the application if it didn't send the full packet.